# Why passing e.target.name is not working here in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to pass the remove method and remove the item from the array.
Here's the code

https://codesandbox.io/embed/heuristic-star-chie9

```js
remove(item,e){
    const x = e.target.name
    console.log(x)
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return {
        friends : prevState.friends.x.filter((k) => (k.name !== item.name) )
      }
    } )
}
```

```html
<button name='deactive' onClick={() => {props.remove(item)}}> REMOVE 
</button>
```

Comment: Because you don't pass the event object through. Why did you think it *would* work?

Comment: i was just experimenting with my code

Comment: So why are you asking why it doesn't work? Don't [program by coincidence](https://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/coincidence).

Comment: I wanted to create a remove button in my main parent component. Pass it to child component via props. I have two states for my component, active and Deactive.
I wanted to change the state by triggering event on Button. Button has name attribute same as state name. so I thought I could change the state with e.target.name.

Comment: thanks for reference to that blog . Enjoyed reading it lol

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the event like that :

```
<button name='deactive' onClick={(event) => {props.remove(item, event)}}> REMOVE 
</button>
```

Comment: it shows The above error occurred in the <App> component: